# Excel VBA function how to detect if numberformat of cell is number

Tags: excel, vba, format, number-formatting

I want to detect whether a cell has the numberformat number. If the cell is not set to numberformat number, then an error message should be logged.
For example:
Cell A1 has the entry 1000. The check should detect whether the cell format is set to number. All other numberformats (like general, percent, currency etc.) are not allowed.

The check with the function numberformat works for General, Percent (format code "0.00%"), Scientific etc. but not for Number (format codes "0" or "0.00" etc.).

I tried these functions (in a shortened version):

- Cell.Numberformat = "0"
- Cell.Numberformat = "0,00"
- Cell.Numberformat = "0.00"
- Cell.Numberformat = "Number"
- Cell.Numberformat = "General Number"
- Cell.Numberformat = "#.##0,00"
- Cell.Numberformat = "#,##0.00"

The correct separator in my Excel language is "," but also with the English writing the function doesnt work.

Although the number value in the cell is set to the correct number format, the check returns False.
Additionally, the check works with all the other number format checks like percent, scientific, general etc. via the above function (e.g. Cell.Numberformat = "General" or Cell.Numberformat = "0.00%")

Have anyone an idea, which check function should I use?

Comment: Why not use `Dim tStr As String: tStr = Range("A1").NumberFormat` (or whatever range your correct one is at) to determine which one you want and then check with `If Cell.Numberformat <> tStr Then ....`?

Comment: Thanks @Notus_Panda for your comment. The solution was the function expression ....NumberFormatLocal like....  mentioned by CLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past, you may need to tweak it for your specific requirement.

```
Function is_formatted_as_number(rng As Range) As Boolean
    is_formatted_as_number = Not (rng.NumberFormatLocal Like "*[A-Za-z%]*")
End Function
```

It simply examines the text returned for the format label for text or % symbol. You can add other symbols etc. such as £ $ if you wish.

To test..

```
If is_formatted_as_number(ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)) Then
    ...
Else
    ....
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the function expression NumberFormatLocal Like ..... solved my problem! :)